# How can GIMP save older version of xcf file format

Tags: version, gimp, xcf

GIMP's native file format has evolved during the years. If there is an external tool that is capable to read `*.xcf` files then it still can happen that the tool cannot read the file, complaining about unknown file format, or something like this:

```
read XCF: unsupported file version: v011
```

How can I save the image into the older version of the `*.xcf` format?

Comment: Do you happen to use my xcf library? https://github.com/gonutz/xcf

Comment: I am actually just Googling because I want to update this library to read the latest formats :-)

Answer (score 3):

GIMP is smart enough and alerts you when you save the file.

[image: GIMP alerts that the new format will be used]

This alert is displayed when your image contains something that GIMP cannot save into the old format, therefore the new version is needed. If you want to save the old format then you need to remove everything from your image that is too modern and impossible to store in an older format of `*.xcf`.

GIMP also tells what feature in the image is/are exactly the one/ones that make GIMP to use the newer version.

In the above picture, you can see that the layer mode setting is not compatible with the old format, therefore GIMP will use the new one.

In order to get rid of this message, you need to change the layer mode by right-clicking *each* layer, and change them in the `Edit Layer Attributes` -> `Mode` drop-down from `Normal` to `Normal (l)` or similar. The drop-down shows only the Default layer modes by default but if you click the little icon on the right side of the drop-down then you can switch to the Legacy layer modes.

[image: Change here the set of the options in the drop-down list]

If you try to save the `*.xcf` again then the above message disappears and the older version of `*.xcf` format will be used.

Maybe you still have some other settings in your image that are not compatible with the old file format. You need to hunt them down one-by-one but sooner or later you will be able to save in the older format.